# Stop glossary cross-references from showing in pagelist

Tags: glossary

I would like to cross-reference glossary entries within the glossary, but I don't want page numbers to appear for those cross-references. Right now, I have:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{LaTeX}{
  name=LaTeX,
  description={A typesetting engine for producing beautiful \glspl{document}}
}
\newglossaryentry{document}{
  name=document,
  description={A file that contains a bunch of text}
}

\begin{document}

This is a sentence about \gls{LaTeX} and \glspl{document}.
\glsaddall
\clearpage
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

The entry for "document" says it is referenced on pages 1 and 2, but I only want it to show the reference from page 1. However, I would like to keep the hyperref link to the "document" entry from the "LaTeX" entry.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\glshyperlink[document]{document}` in glossary description in place of `\glsps`.

```tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{LaTeX}{
  name=LaTeX,
  description={A typesetting engine for producing beautiful \glshyperlink{document}{document}}
}
\newglossaryentry{document}{
  name=document,
  description={A file that contains a bunch of text}
}

\begin{document}

This is a sentence about \gls{LaTeX} and \glspl{document}.
\glsaddall
\clearpage
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry! I was actually using hyperref to get links with the cross-references, which I was hoping to be able to retain, but then I forgot that was relevant and removed hyperref from the MWE!

Comment: @A.R. OK. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on jlab's answer, and further examination of the glossaries package, I was able to add the following segment to my preamble to address the problem by redefining the `\gls` family of commands only within the evaluation of the `\printglossary` command. (If you are using a different command to print your glossary, e.g. `\printglossaries`, that command name should be substituted in the `\AddToHook` calls.

```
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/printglossary/before}{%
    % SAVE THE ORIGINAL DEFINITIONS
    \let\o@gls\gls%
    \let\o@Gls\Gls%
    \let\o@glspl\glspl%
    \let\o@Glspl\Glspl%
    %
    % NEW DEFINITIONS THAT DON'T PRODUCE PAGE ENTRIES
    \renewcommand*\gls[1]{\glshyperlink[\glsentryname{#1}\@empty]{#1}}%
    \renewcommand*\Gls[1]{\glshyperlink[\Glsentryname{#1}\@empty]{#1}}%
    \renewcommand*\glspl[1]{\glshyperlink[\glsentryplural{#1}\@empty]{#1}}%
    \renewcommand*\Glspl[1]{\glshyperlink[\Glsentryplural{#1}\@empty]{#1}}%
}
\AddToHook{cmd/printglossary/after}{%
    % RESTORE ORIGINAL DEFINITIONS AFTER GLOSSARY
    \let\gls\o@gls%
    \let\Gls\o@Gls%
    \let\glspl\o@glspl%
    \let\Glspl\o@Glspl%
}
\makeatother
```

If the glossary is at the end of the document, this can be simplified, as we don't need to restore the original behaviors:

```
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/printglossary/before}{%
    \renewcommand*\gls[1]{\glshyperlink[\glsentryname{#1}\@empty]{#1}}%
    \renewcommand*\Gls[1]{\glshyperlink[\Glsentryname{#1}\@empty]{#1}}%
    \renewcommand*\glspl[1]{\glshyperlink[\glsentryplural{#1}\@empty]{#1}}%
    \renewcommand*\Glspl[1]{\glshyperlink[\Glsentryplural{#1}\@empty]{#1}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I also ended up doing the same for the table of contents and list of figures, which I also didn't want showing up in the glossary.